# How do I insert a node into a different typedef struct?

Tags: c

I've been trying to insert a node into a list using the "void push()"-function, but I can't really get it to work. Basically what I want this to do is for it to insert every new node created from (typedef struct node) to the head of the list (typedef struct list) and to be able to display it.
I'm pretty new to C and for now I'm most familiar with using stdio.h and stdlib.h.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}N;

typedef struct list
{
    N *head;
}L;

void push(N** headloc, int newdata)
{
    N *newnode = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
    newnode->data= newdata;
    newnode->next = (*headloc);
    newnode->prev = NULL;

    if((*headloc) != NULL)
        (*headloc)->prev = newnode;
        (*headloc) = newnode; 
        (*headloc)->prev = NULL;
}

void printlist(N *n)
{
    printf("Linked list: ");
    N *last;
    while (n != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        last = n;
        n = n->next;
    }
} 

int main()
{
    N *head = NULL;
    push(&head, 2);
    printlist(head);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You know, that indentation is not defining the logic but only makes your code more readable, right?. How many lines of code do you think, are depending on the condition in `if((*headloc) != NULL)`?

Comment: @Gerhardh hi, sorry my english isn't really the best. What do you mean by indentation?

Comment: indentation means the leading spaces in every line. You have 3 lines indented below your `if` in `push` function. But only the first line is part of the `if`. The other 2 lines are always executed. You should apply correct indentation. The logic should be the same as visually indicated by your code.

Comment: Besides that, you should tell us where your problem is. What is stopping you from getting it wo work. What is your output and expected output?

Comment: What's the purpose of `last = n;`? You never use `last`.

Comment: The lines `(*headloc) = newnode;` and `(*headloc)->next = NULL;` lines should be moved left 4 spaces to line up with the `if`, but the `(*headloc)->next = NULL;` line is actually redundant due to the earlier `newnode->prev = NULL;` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code you have is working (but is leaking memory). In order to store the nodes in a `struct list` (or `L` as you've `typedef`ined it), you need to make your `push` and `printlist` functions take a pointer to an `L` instead.

Example:

```c
void push(L *l, int newdata) {   // An `L` pointer
    N *newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);
    newnode->data = newdata;
    newnode->next = l->head;     // use `L`s head
    newnode->prev = NULL;

    // again, use l->head below:
    if (l->head) l->head->prev = newnode;
    l->head = newnode;
    // (*headloc)->prev = NULL; // newnode->prev is already NULL
}

// A helper function to create and initialize a new list
L *list_create() {
    return calloc(1, sizeof(L));
}

void printlist(L *l) {          // L pointer again
    N *n = l->head;             // and use its head
    printf("Linked list: ");
    // N *last;                 // unused, remove
    while (n) {
        printf("%d ", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

// free resources when you're done with the list
void freelist(L *l) {
    for(N *n = l->head, *nn; n; n = nn) {
        nn = n->next;
        free(n);
    }
    free(l);
}
```

You can then create multiple separate lists and populate them as you wish:

```c
int main() {
    L *l1 = list_create();
    L *l2 = list_create();
    push(l1, 2);
    push(l2, 3);
    push(l1, 4);
    push(l2, 5);
    printlist(l1); // pushed 2 4
    printlist(l2); // pushed 3 5
    freelist(l1);
    freelist(l2);
}
```

Output:

```
Linked list: 4 2 
Linked list: 5 3
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TEndnP79G)

Comment: Just wondering if the L*listcreate is necessary. If I wanted to get rid of that function, how would it affect the argument for push() in int main()? what would be written there instead. I really appreciate you taking your time and presenting a such a good example

Comment: @Anon019 If you remove that, you need to use `calloc` manually to create the list because you need the `L` members to be zeroed at creation. If you use `malloc` you'll have to do `L *l1 = malloc(sizeof *l1); l1->head = NULL;` or else the program will have undefined behavior. I made [another demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xxeoG7ddc) where I've added `tail` to the list too to be able to `push_back` to the end of the list quickly too